# Labels not changing values when combobox value changes in vb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My Visual Basic program fetches values from an Access database and places them in labels. The data returned from the database depends on the value selected in a combo box and is supposed to change as the combobox value changes but to my surprise, the labels keep displaying only the first values that were displayed first even when they must change. I tried to assign the label texts to nothing just before each database access but it still displays the previous values. What could be the issue here that I cannot get these labels to change text? Please help. Here is the code I use to access the database and place in labels:

```
    Me.p.Text = Nothing
    Me.tq.Text = Nothing
    Me.pd.Text = Nothing
    Me.ba.Text = Nothing
    Me.o.Text = Nothing
    Me.pm.Text = Nothing
    Me.tv.Text = Nothing
    Me.tqr.Text = Nothing
    Me.dff.Text = Nothing
    Try
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cmd2.Connection = cnn
        cmd3.Connection = cnn
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT distinct(brought_price), sum(brought_qtty), sum(brought_paid), sum(brought_bal),recieved_qtty,sum(brought_qtty)-recieved_qtty, sum(brought_qtty)*brought_price from brought_coffee, farmer, centre_weigh " & _
                                "where brought_date=? and farmer_centre=? and" & _
                                " brought_coffee.farmer_num=farmer.farmer_num and weigh_date=? and weigh_centre=? and brought_coffee.brought_date=centre_weigh.weigh_date and farmer_centre=weigh_centre group by brought_price,recieved_qtty"
            MessageBox.Show(Me.dtc.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtc.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt2", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.cc.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 2)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt3", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtc.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt4", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.cc.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 2)

            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT sum(brought_qtty) from brought_coffee,farmer where coffee_grade='O' and brought_date=? and farmer_centre=? and" & _
                                " brought_coffee.farmer_num=farmer.farmer_num"
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@dt5", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtc.Text
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@dt6", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value =     Me.cc.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 2)

            cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT sum(brought_qtty) from brought_coffee,farmer where coffee_grade='P' and brought_date=? and farmer_centre=? and" & _
                                " brought_coffee.farmer_num=farmer.farmer_num"
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@dt7", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtc.Text
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@dt8", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.cc.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 2)

            myData = cmd.ExecuteReader
            myData2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader
            myData3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader
            'MessageBox.Show("check 1")

            While myData.Read()
                'MessageBox.Show("check 1")
                Dim pr As String = myData(0).ToString
                Dim qtty As String = myData(1).ToString
                Dim pd As String = myData(2).ToString
                Dim bl As String = myData(3).ToString
                Dim rq As String = myData(4).ToString
                Dim dq As String = myData(5).ToString
                Dim tvp As String = myData(6).ToString
                'MessageBox.Show("quantity" & pr)
                Me.p.Text = pr
                Me.tq.Text = qtty
                Me.pd.Text = pd
                Me.ba.Text = bl
                Me.tqr.Text = rq
                Me.dff.Text = dq
                Me.tv.Text = tvp

            End While
            myData.Close()

            While myData2.Read()
                Dim od As String = myData2(0).ToString
                'MessageBox.Show(od)
                Me.o.Text = od
            End While

            myData2.Close()

            While myData3.Read()
                Dim pmm As String = myData3(0).ToString
                Me.pm.Text = pmm
            End While
            myData3.Close()
            cnn.Close()
```

`dtc` and `cc` are the textboxes where database values are compared with in the selected

Comment: What flavor of vb is that code?  Is it VB.Net?

Comment: @HansUp I think its safe to say .NET. If he's getting `cmd.ExecuteReader` to work in VBA I'd be interested in how...

Comment: @ken the SQL statements in cmd2 and cmd3 can only return a single row. The SQL statement in cmd *could* return more than one row. The result of your loop assigns the text boxes the values to the last row (if there is more than one row). Could that be your problem?

Comment: are you using webforms or windows forms?

Comment: @ConradFrix let me check that however my statement is meant to fetch only single values.

Comment: @Nudier am using windows forms

Comment: The SQL in cmd returns a single row

Comment: @ken okay well that's one possibility elminitated. I noticed you have a Try block. Do you have a Catch? If you do what's in it?

Comment: @ConradFrix the catch has `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)`. Not giving an exception either. My only worry is why won't it fetch when values of combos change?

Comment: @Ken the code as written should perform as expected. We've eliminated unexpected rows. We've eliminated swallowing exceptions. The only thing left, is that you need to step through the code and see that 1) your code fires when you think it should 2) That the values make sense 3) that nothing else is firing which would overwrite the TextBox values

Comment: Yes am doing exactly that and still finding no reason for the unusual result. I thought it could be a common thing but maybe I will go on and check the code further. Thanks alot @ConradFrix